# Telegram bot webhooks, servlet on Tomcat and openshift cloud

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, openshift, telegram-bot

I have a problem with telegram webhooks: it don't send me any HTTPS POST info.

Telegram Bot API's `setWebhook` method answer is positive:

```
{
    ok: true,
    result: true,
    description: "Webhook was set"
}
```

My `doPost` method doesn't depend of any POST params, but it not called when i send some messages to my bot. 
When i execute this servlet via RestClient chrome extension, all works fine.

I read about possible problems in certificates SSL, but I think that should be ok with openshift.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a case of Openshift you can do just simple setup Webhook with passing only URL, but not a certificate. Openshift has a certificate already on a host, so you do not need to generate it by yourself and pass. Moreover, webhook won't work at all with your certificate in case of Openshift.